# Rearrange two sets of ten columns into two columns

Tags: sql, excel, vba, pivot-table, unpivot

I have a table with a name column and ten question columns with the name and answers under the relevant columns.

How do I format the ten question columns into one column with each question on a separate row and a new column for the answer to that particular question?

Comment: This looks like a basic translation function isnt'it ?

Comment: This sounds like you have a "many-to-one" / "one-to-many" relationship issue. Could you please post code that you are using and what you have tried so far?

Comment: d-stroyer, I tried copy and transpose, but this only flips horizontal to vertical. Hexie, Yes, so one row with all the questions to 10 rows with a question on each for each name. I have no code so far, so was really looking for some pointers e.g. VBA or SQL. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have sample screenshots of what you currently have and how you want it to look like? (doing a few manually shouldn't be too difficult) I'm not too sure your question is clear enough.

Comment: Thanks Jerry. Unfortunately, I don't have permission to add images.

Comment: You can still put the link to those images :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is called a 'reverse pivot'. Construct a PivotTable with multiple consolidation ranges (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+D, P if necessary) and double click on the Grand Total. The correct answers would have to be added in some other way however, since not given in your question.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Which ranges do I consolidate?

Comment: This might be helpful? [unpivot](http://superuser.com/questions/78439/is-it-possible-to-unpivot-or-reverse-pivot-in-excel)

Comment: Thanks pnuts and zx8754 - that's exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: Ha ha! Appreciate the help.